# getCurrentPosition() equivalent for Audio recorder

Tags: android

In android media player has  getCurrentPosition() which tell me how long that media has been played (in second).  But why there is no equivalent for media recorder? How can I find out how long has elapsed when recoding an audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find out how long has
>   elapsed when recoding an audio?

Keep track of it yourself, using `SystemClock.elapsedTime()`.